# How to convert String with BOM of Windows-1252 into UTF-8 without BOM

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

I am having windows-1252 string which includes

> Latin capital letter reverse E(unicode U+018E)

When I am converting the string to UTF-8 the string comes with BOM `"þÿ"` (UTF-16 BE, hex representation : FE FF) added at the start of line.

How should I convert it to UTF-8 without BOM?

Here is my code.

When I am converting it to ASCII i am getting "?" symbol.
And if I am converting to UTF-8 i am getting "BOM" character issue with space added after each character in that line.

Here is my output. I am trying to convert text file to pdf file.

[Windows-1252 to ASCII](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAxRe.png)  and  [Windows-1252 to UTF-8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldkS8.png)

And also If I want to copy text content as it is (same spacing and structures) , is there any way to do it??

```
private OutputStream getStreamFromTextFile(byte[] fileInput) throws IOException, COSVisitorException
{
    //Made the changes for DS text alignment.
   OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDRectangle rectangle_A4 = new PDRectangle(598f, 824f);
    PDPage page = new PDPage(rectangle_A4); 
    doc.addPage(page);
    PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(doc,page);

    PDFont pdfFont = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
    float fontSize = 14;
    float leading = 1.5f * fontSize;

    PDRectangle mediabox = page.getMediaBox();
    float margin = 40;
    float width = mediabox.getWidth() - 2*margin;
    float startX = mediabox.getLowerLeftX() + margin;
    float startY = mediabox.getUpperRightY() - margin;

    /*
    String data = new String(fileInput,Charset.forName("windows-1252")); 
    byte[] Ascii_Bytes = data.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
    String text = new String(Ascii_Bytes,"US-ASCII");
    */

    String data = new String(fileInput,Charset.forName("windows-1252")); 
    byte[] UTF_8_Bytes = data.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    String text = new String(UTF_8_Bytes,"UTF-8");

    /*
    String text = new String(fileInput,Charset.forName("windows-1252"));
    */

    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    int lastSpace = -1;
    while (text.length() > 0)
    {
        int spaceIndex = text.indexOf(' ', lastSpace + 1);
        if (spaceIndex < 0)
            spaceIndex = text.length();
        String subString = text.substring(0, spaceIndex);
        float size = fontSize * pdfFont.getStringWidth(subString) / 1000;
        System.out.printf("'%s' - %f of %f\n", subString, size, width);
        if (size > width-(margin-10))
        {
            if (lastSpace < 0)
                lastSpace = spaceIndex;
            subString = text.substring(0, lastSpace);
            lines.add(subString);
            text = text.substring(lastSpace).trim();
            System.out.printf("'%s' is line\n", subString);
            lastSpace = -1;
        }
        else if (spaceIndex == text.length())
        {
            lines.add(text);
            System.out.printf("'%s' is line\n", text);
            text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            lastSpace = spaceIndex;
        }
    }


    stream.beginText();
    stream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
    stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(startX, startY);  
    float currentY = startY;
    for (String line: lines)
    {
       currentY -= leading;

           if (currentY<=margin)
           {
             stream.endText();
             stream.close();
             PDRectangle new_rectangle_A4 = new PDRectangle(598f, 824f);
             PDPage new_page = new PDPage(new_rectangle_A4); 
             doc.addPage(new_page);
             stream = new PDPageContentStream(doc,new_page);
             stream.beginText();
             stream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
             stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(startX, startY);  
             currentY = startY;
           }

       stream.drawString(line);
       stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0, -leading);
    }

    stream.endText(); 
    stream.close();

    doc.save(outputStream);
    doc.close();
   return outputStream;
```

}

Comment: 1252 is a single byte encoding that does not contain that glyph, if it contains the two bytes 01+8E something is likely broken in terms of encoding.  How to remove/omit a BOM from a Unicode string depends on how you are creating the string and what you do with it, which you have not shown

Comment: Also, FEFF is a UTF-16 BOM, not UTF-8. There seems to be something wrong with the conversion, please check both the configured input- and output-charsets.

Comment: Edit your question and show your code.  Java doesn’t have a “windows-1252 string”;  all String objects are UTF-16.  Only byte arrays can be associated with other charsets.

Comment: If the converted data begins with bytes `FE FF`, you performed a conversion to UTF-16, not UTF-8 (the UTF-8 BOM is `EF BB BF`). For instance, if you use `String.getBytes("UTF-16")`, it emits a BOM so you know which endian is used. To convert to a specific UTF-16 endian, use `getBytes("UTF-16LE")` or `getBytes("UTF-16BE")` instead, then no BOM is emitted. `getBytes("UTF-8")` does not have any endian issues, and does not emit a BOM. On the other hand, if you are saying that you are converting a UTF-16 string with BOM to UTF-8, simply skip the BOM before converting the rest of the UTF-16 data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.The input Bytes are of windows-1252.

Comment: Instead of "þÿ", please show byte values in hexadecimal for bytes [edit]. Also, your premise that you have Ǝ in Windows-1252 encoded text is incorrect because that character set does not have that character. And, as others have pointed out "Windows-1252 string" in the context of Java does not make sense literally because Java strings are UTF-16 (as are VB4/5/6, VB, VBA, VBScript, JavaScript, C#, SQL nvarchar,…).

Comment: May be that is the issue. I am getting reversed E in Windows 1252. I will check with encoding. Thanks to all.

Comment: I think its a bug in pdfbox 1.8.x...when i am doing the same thing with pdfbox 2 .I am not getting any BOM character in the document. Is there any way to support unicode encoding in pdfbox 1.8?